# how to get the log likelihood for a logistic regression model in sklearn?

Tags: math, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, log-likelihood

I'm using a logistic regression model in sklearn and I am interested in retrieving the log likelihood for such a model, so to perform an ordinary likelihood ratio test as suggested [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/118301/99338).

The model is using the [log loss](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html) as scoring rule.  In the documentation, the log loss is defined *"as the negative log-likelihood of the true labels given a probabilistic classifier’s predictions"*. However, the value is always positive, whereas the log likelihood should be negative. As an example:

```python
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss

lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_prob = lr.predict_proba(X_test)
log_loss(y_test, y_prob)    # 0.66738
```

I do not see any method in the documentation for the model, is there any other possibility that I am currently not aware of?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read closely; the log loss is the *negative* log-likelihood. Since log-likelihood is indeed as you say negative, its negative will be a positive number.

Let's see an example with dummy data:

```python
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
import numpy as np

y_true = np.array([0, 1, 1])
y_pred = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.9])

log_loss(y_true, y_pred)
# 0.60671964791658428
```

Now, let's compute manually the log-likelihood elements (i.e. one value per label-prediction pair), using the formula given in the scikit-learn docs you have linked to without the minus sign:

```python
log_likelihood_elements = y_true*np.log(y_pred) + (1-y_true)*np.log(1-y_pred)
log_likelihood_elements
# array([-0.10536052, -1.60943791, -0.10536052])
```

Now, given the log-likelihood elements (which are indeed negative), the log loss is the negative of their sum, divided by the number of samples:

```python
-np.sum(log_likelihood_elements)/len(y_true)
# 0.60671964791658428

log_loss(y_true, y_pred) == -np.sum(log_likelihood_elements)/len(y_true)
# True
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am pretty stupid today. That means, the lower the better when using the log loss. Or I might change sign and treat it as log likelihood - right?

Comment: @MattiaPaterna Every quantity described as "loss", implies "the lower the better"

Comment: @Mattia Paterna:  Cross-Entropy loss is negative log-likelihood because you are maximizing it in Maximum Likelyhood Estimation & use optimization algorithm minimization, thus in order to get maximization you need to multiply for -1

Answer (score 2):

To get the log likelihood you can calculate:

```
-log_loss(y_true, y_pred)*len(y_true)
```