# How to calculate the joint log-likelihood for Bernoulli Naive Bayes

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes, bernoulli-probability

For a classification problem using [BernoulliNB](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html#bernoulli-naive-bayes) , how to calculate the joint log-likelihood. The joint likelihood it to be calculated by below formula, where y(d) is the array of actual output (not predicted values) and x(d) is the data set of features.

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48185090/how-to-get-the-log-likelihood-for-a-logistic-regression-model-in-sklearn) and read the [documentation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/bac89c2/sklearn/naive_bayes.py#L839) but it didn't exactly served my purpose. Can somebody please 
help.[image]

Comment: can't you just use the attributes `.class_log_prior_` or `.feature_log_prob_` of the trained classifier?

Comment: Hi Daniel, no cant's use them. Have to calculate according to this formula only.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at [the code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/bac89c2/sklearn/naive_bayes.py#L932), it looks like there is a hidden undocumented `._joint_log_likelihood(self, X)` function in the BernoulliNB which computes the joint log-likelihood.

Its implementation is somewhat consistent with what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
- The solution is to count the positive input variables of the 
  positive output function.
- We achieve this by counting the 
  positive output variables or y of index y or y of 1 or y[1] or 
  data[idx][1].

- The first block of code is the **training** and *learning*.
- The second block of code is the **testing** and *counting*.

- train, test, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(Xs[0], 
  ys[0], test_size=1./3, random_state=r)
  naive = BernoulliNB(alpha= 10**-7)
  model = naive.fit(train, train_labels)
  joint_log_train = model._joint_log_likelihood(train)
- l = [np.append(x,y) for x, y in zip(train, train_labels)]

- # Write your code below this line.
- def count(data, label):
    x = 0
    for idx, l in enumerate(label):
        if (l == True):
            x += data[idx][1]
        else:
            x += data[idx][0]
    return x
- for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(Xs, ys)):
    train, test, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(x, y, 
    test_size=1./3, random_state=r)
    for j, a in enumerate(alphas):   
        naive = BernoulliNB(alpha = a)
        model = naive.fit(train, train_labels)
        joint_log_train = model._joint_log_likelihood(train)
        joint_log_test = model._joint_log_likelihood(test)
        train_jil[i][j] = count(joint_log_train, train_labels)
        test_jil[i][j] = count(joint_log_test, test_labels)
```

Comment: You can add a brief explanation

Comment: Please add more details to your answer explaining how it solves the problem

Comment: Added details to the answer